# Inheriting ConfigurationElement to Deserialize App.config Text Elements

Tags: c#

I would like to provide a custom configuration section in the ***App.config*** file of my project.  The default implementation of ***ConfigurationSection*** loads/stores values in the attribute section of the XML element.  I rather not store data in the attribute section but instead the text field of the XML element.  By inheriting from ***ConfigurationElement***, I can change this behavior to load/store values in the XML element text field.

The article [Extend ConfigurationElement to Deserialize Text Elements](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/xml/configurationtextelement.aspx) provided a lot of guidance on this effort.

```cs
public class RemoteSite : ConfigurationSection {
    [ConfigurationProperty("Hi")]
    public string Hi { get; set; }

    [ConfigurationProperty("Me")]
    public ConfigurationTextElement<string> Me {
        get { return (ConfigurationTextElement<string>)this["Me"]; }
        set { this["Me"] = value; } }
}

public class ConfigurationTextElement<T> : ConfigurationElement {
    private T _value;

    protected override void DeserializeElement(XmlReader reader, bool serializeCollectionKey) {
        _value = (T)reader.ReadElementContentAs(typeof(T), null);
    }

    public T Value {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; } }
}
```

When using the ***RemoteSite*** I have an implicit conversion error when trying to save/get data from the ***ConfigurationTextElement*** property.

```cs
var site = new RemoteSite();

//Works as expected
site.Hi = "Hello";
string greeting = site.Hi;

//Gives the following error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConfigurationTextElement<string>' to 'string'.
site.Me = "I am";
string me = site.Me;
```

How can I fix the casting issue on either the ***RemoteSite*** or ***ConfigurationTextElement*** side of the code.  I want the user to be able to get/set the data as a string since the user doesn't care how the ***RemoteSite*** is storing the information.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you getting the error here `site.Me = "I am";` or on the line below?

Comment: Both give an error.